# object reference not set to an instance of an object >> insert query c#

Tags: c#, insert

I have this method which inserts data to two different tables in my database from textboxes and `Datagridview` , The first insert query executing normally but the second one throws an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Here is my method:

```
private void InsertAll()
{
    DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save all ? ", "Warnning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

    if (Result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = Cn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                Cn.Open();

                // Insert the header first Due to one-to-many relationship 
                cmd.CommandText = @" INSERT INTO DocDtls ( DocNum, zDate, Warehouse, Orientation,TransType,UserName )
                                     VALUES (@prm1, @prm2, @prm3, @prm4, @prm5, @prm6);";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm1", txtDocNum.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm2", txtDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")); 
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm3", cmbWh.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm4", txtOrient.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm5", txtTransType.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm6", txtUser.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Insert the Details >> where the problem start to occur
                if (txtTransType.Text == "Release")
                {
                    cmd2.Connection = Cn;
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    // Cn.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < DGV1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cmd2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Transactions ( DocNum, Code, QtyIn, QtyOut, BalanceAfter, Remarks, Unit) 
                                             VALUES (@prm1, @prm2, @prm3, @prm4, @prm5, @prm6,@prm7);";

                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm1", txtDocNum.Text);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm2", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Code"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm3", 0);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm4", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Qty"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm5", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm6", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Remarks"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm7", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Unit"].Value);

                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MessageBox.Show("Registered", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd2.Connection = Cn;
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    //Cn.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < DGV1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        cmd2.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Transactions ( DocNum, Code, QtyIn, QtyOut, BalanceAfter, Remarks, Unit )
                                             VALUES (@prm1, @prm2, @prm3, @prm4, @prm5, @prm6,@prm7);";

                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm1", txtDocNum.Text);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm2", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Code"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm3", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Qty"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm4", 0);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm5", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm6", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Remarks"].Value);
                        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm7", DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Unit"].Value);

                        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        MessageBox.Show("Registered", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            Cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I suspected that the connection might be closed in some point so I added opening connection again after the first insert but the problem still happening.

What's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does `cmd2` come from? Also, you know it poor practice to try to re-use the same connection object, right? Re-using the same object breaks the built in connection pooling feature, and actually makes things slower and creates bottlenecks. You really are better off creating a new connection object for most queries.

Comment: Thanks for reply , At fist there as only `SqlCommand cmd`  but when i tried to reuse it in the second insert query with the same variables names it caused an issue I don't remember the specific context but it as related to variables names so , I created `cmd2` then the problem solved .

Comment: About the second point , Do you mean that I need to make another SqlConnection identical to `cn` but with different name  ?

Comment: Almost. I mean `Cn` should not exist at all as a global. Instead, only have the connection string available. Yes, I know this will mean updating a lot of other code in the application, but it **WILL** measurably improve performance.

Comment: I will consider it thanks for advice , About the error what about it ?

Comment: Just posted. Took some time work through the code.

Comment: Thank you so much , I appreciate your effort .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. There's a lot of code, so likely a typo or other issue or two still here. Pay attention to the comments:

```
private void InsertAll()
{    
    using (var cn = new SqlConnection(Cn.ConnectionString)) // Using block around the connection
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("", cn))
    {
        //removed the try/catch. Instead, wrap the try/catch around this method call
        
        cmd.CommandText = @" INSERT INTO DocDtls ( DocNum, zDate, Warehouse, Orientation,TransType,UserName )
                                     Values (@prm1, @prm2, @prm3, @prm4, @prm5, @prm6);";
        //AddWithValue() can be dangerously slow, but usually still safe for single simple INSERT
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm1", txtDocNum.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm2", txtDate.Value); //If you're converting a DateTime to a string for use in SQL, you're doing something VERY WRONG
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm3", cmbWh.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm4", txtOrient.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm5", txtTransType.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm6", txtUser.Text);
        
        cn.Open(); //Wait until last possible moment to call cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Normally don't re-use the same connection, but 
        // within a single operation context like this it's okay
        // not only for the connection, but for the command, too.
        cmd.CommandText = @" INSERT INTO Transactions ( DocNum, Code, QtyIn, QtyOut, BalanceAfter, Remarks, Unit )
                             Values (@DocNum, @Code, @QtyIn, @QtyOut, @BalanceAfter, @Remarks,@Unit);";

        cmd.Parameters.Clear(); //Missing this line is why you had to create cmd2 before.
        // Use exact types from the database here. Don't let ADO.Net try to infer these.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DocNum", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = txtDocNum.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Code", SqlDbType.Char, 7);
        // the "= 0" at the end of the next two lines are important.
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QtyIn", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@QtyOut", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 0;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@BalanceAfter", SqlDbType.Decimal);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Remarks", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);

        // We can also set the Qty switch outside the loop
        var qtyKey = (txtTransType.Text == "Release")?"@QtyOut":"@QtyIn";

        for (int i = 0; i < DGV1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // Only change parameter values inside the loop           
            cmd.Parameters["@Code"] = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Code"].Value;
            cmd.Parameters[qtyKey].Value = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Qty"].Value;
            cmd.Parameters["@BalanceAfter"] = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["BalanceAfter"].Value;
            cmd.Parameters["@Remarks"] = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Remarks"].Value;
            cmd.Parameters["@Unit"] = DGV1.Rows[i].Cells["Unit"].Value;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
       // No need to call cn.Close(). Using blocks take care of it.
    }
}
```

Note I removed the initial prompt/check, the try/catch, and the final complete message. Those things belong with the caller, like this:

```
DialogResult Result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save all ? ", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
if (Result == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    try 
    {
        InsertAll()
        MessageBox.Show("Registered", "Done", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString(), "Error Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Eventually you would also move the method (and other database access) be a static member of a *separate class*, where the required information is passed as arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort , I revised the code , edited datatypes and corrected all typos but I get this Error "Additional information: The parameterized query '(@DocNum nvarchar(50),@Code nvarchar(50),@QtyIn int,@QtyOut int,' expects the parameter '@Remarks', which was not supplied" the code expects all datagridview cells to be filled with data but the fact is some of them are optional and can be null in my db , Is there a solution for that ?

Comment: You set the parameter's `.Value` to `DBNull.Value`. Also, I had a typo on the parameter name (fixed now).